# How to fix script to umount device without password?

Tags: debian, sudoers

I have added a file named: `umountscript` to `/etc/sudoers.d/` with this directive:

```
xikri ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/home/x/umountscript.sh
```

inside umountscript.sh I have this code:

```
umount /mnt/devicex
```

But when I run the script I get this message:

```
umount: /mnt/devicex: umount failed: Operation not permitted
```

Do I need to do something additional to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to invoke sudo otherwise sudoers is ignored, so

```
umount /mnt/devicex
```